# Whats the purpose of Index.php in MVC Frameworks?

Tags: model-view-controller

I want a good understandable description of index.php in MVC Frameworks... I have worked in Magento and Codeignitor...
In Magento URL's index.php is called front controller but in codeignitor what it is? 
Plz clear the concept of index.php in MVC Frameworks?

Comment: In most frameworks, the `index.php` acts as the dispatcher, that is, the first one to receive all requests and then route it to different controllers, it's also when the required controller is initialized and all the bootstrapping is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is your entry point from where it will dispatch / route your URL to the appropriate controllers/actions. You don't have to name in *index.php* though, you can give it whatever name you want, as long as you call the file, it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

In codeigniter index.php is the entry point of the application. Its not a controller. It sets your environment, initializes your config/route/autoload etc. and then loads your requested controller.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, index.php mainly works as a bootstrapper. It initializes all most variables and puts your application in a usable state. Almost all calls are routed through it. If you want you can also hide index.php from your visible path using .htaccess. For example in yii you can use this guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/